# Using object and template in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I've a class with template:

```
template<class T> class MyClass {
public:
      MyClass() { _genericObj = new T; }
      ~MyClass() { delete _genericObj; }
      void doSomething() { _genericObj.do(); }
private:
      T* _genericObj;
};
```

And another class:

```
class AnotherClass {
public:
     AnotherClass(MyClass &obj) { this->_obj = obj; }
     ~AnotherClass() {  }
     doMagic() { _obj->doSomething(); }
private
     MyClass* _obj;
}
```

Is it right to use in AnotherClass an instance of MyClass without angular parenthesis (for generality)?
If this example is wrong, how can I correct my code? Thank u so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decide whether you need a concrete type, by specifying a template parameter for `MyClass`, or whether you want `AnotherClass` to be a class template too. You also have the problem that you are passing a reference to some kind of `MyClass` in the constructor, but you are trying to initialize a pointer to it. The way to fix that really depends on what you want to achieve, these examples assume your `AnotherClass` will own a dynamically allocated object of type `MyClass<SomeType>`:

```
class AnotherClass {
public:
     AnotherClass(MyClass<int> &obj) { this->obj_ = new MyClass<int>(obj); }
     ~AnotherClass() { delete obj_; }
     doMagic() { obj_->doSomething(); }
private
     MyClass<int>* obj_;
}
```

or

```
template <typename T>
class AnotherClass {
public:
     AnotherClass(MyClass<T> &obj) { this->obj_ = new MyClass<T>(obj); }
     ~AnotherClass() {  delete obj_;} 
     doMagic() { obj_->doSomething(); }
private
     MyClass<T>* obj_;
}
```

Note that in C++ names starting with an underscore are reserved for the implementation, so I have changed `_obj` for `obj_`.

Comment: The second example is my case. Thank you so much!

Comment: typename or class in AnotherClass? I need to pass an object.

Comment: @vdn in this context, `typename` and `class` are completely equivalent, so it is up to you.